# Font-Awesome CSS stylesheet appearing in chrome only

Tags: html, css, web

I am doing a freelancing website and i am using css html js and php
The problem is when i refer to my font awesome css sheet in my local folders it opens great in google chrome

But when i open it in edge or firefox the icons of do not appear (facebook icon,instagram...etc)

[this is the picture of my ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPK96.jpg)

Comment: provide your code, snippet / fiddle

Comment: Check for any errors in console. Clear cache and reload.

Comment: Can you send your project structure
I think font awesome font files are not loading.

Comment: i added the picture to my question plz see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and it's related to the cross-domain issue that Mozilla doesn't allow such requests. 
Read more here: http://code-epicenter.com/font-awesome-is-not-showingworking-in-mozilla-firefox/

P.S: I don't have enough reputation points to make a comment, hence writing it in the answer. Thank you for not down-voting because of that.